# Как записать строку n размера в Си

Tags: c, строки

Допустим пользователь вводит n символов в строке. Как их записать и вывести?
Я пытался так

```
char *str;
str=malloc(sizeof(char)*x(тут надо как то узнать размер строки);
fgets(str,strlen(str),stdin);
printf("%s",str);
```

Comment: За один раз никак, программа заглядывать в будущее не умеет. Если не хочется делать ограничение, то придётся делать цикл и в цикле делать realloc и fgets пока не встретится EOF или символ переноса строки

Answer (score -1):

Вам надо или знать пределььный размиер строки, больше которого пользователь не введет, либо тогда читать по символу и все время перераспределять память.

Если знаете, что пользователь не введет больше 1000 символов:

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
fgets(str,1000,stdin);
printf("%s",str);
```